# React Router Rerouting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

Hi I have a kinda dumb question. Im working on a react micro service that runs on the url `/checkout` which everything after checkout redirecting to the correct page components. The problem I have is that there is a route in our monolith that has a page with the route `/checkout/settings`. My questions is: is there a way to react-router ignore said route and proceed to navigate away to that page? Thanks

EDIT:

Example.

`/checkout/cart` will redirect to cart page

`/checkout/review` will redirect to review page

`/checkout/pageThatDoesNotExist` will display our 404 page

I want to be able to navigate away from my microservice and go to the monolith when we hit `checkout/settings`

Comment: Do you have any page displayed in /checkout ?

Comment: @muljayan No I dont.

Comment: Does the application on /checkout/settings go to another application or does it preserve the any global state of the application while going to /checkout/settings ?

Comment: Hi @muljayan, going to /checkout/settings leaves the application. No state needs to be persisted

Comment: Hey @joshua-paul-huang why not try using a regular a tag to navigate to /checkout/settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use exact in react router

```
<Route exact path="/checkout" component={}/>
```

if you want to render /checkout/settings instead of /checkout

Comment: Hi Anil, thanks for the response. Ive updated the question with more detail. 

I do have a 404 page that I want to navigate to when the user goes to a page that doesnt exist. I was wondering if there was a way that if i went exactly to that endpoint, that it would actually navigate away. Thanks!